# how to keep initial and final pages next to each other when using momentum-iron-router?

Tags: css, meteor, transform, css-transitions

I am using meteorjs and [momentum-iron-router](https://github.com/percolatestudio/momentum-iron-router/issues/9) to do pages transitions from one route to the next.

The transitions are working but the final page is always below the initial page when transitioning (see below for screenshot).

I am using a standard bootstrap3 layout and styling so both pages just have static positioning.

I tinkered with using absolute positioning but that didn't seem to work very well so I'm really just looking for ideas or a process to work through.

[image]

Comment: @George: w3schools is generally a bad reference compared to MDN. You can exclude it from search results with [this extension from Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef).

Comment: Hah, nice catch. I'm familiar with the inadequacy of the site/organization but dang if it isn't easy to click on them sometimes.